# Simplifying a series of redirections using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My client has an SSL cert for MAINSITE.com but gets a lot of traffic via OTHERSITE.com.

Client would like all visitors to use HTTPS all the time.

So my rules start out by checking for OTHERSITE.com and redirecting to https://MAINSITE.com if found.

Then I check to see if we are using HTTPS and redirect if not.

Then there are a series of rules aimed at using the sub-directories in the URL to pull content and load templates.

My question is whether these rules are as efficient as the should be and if anyone sees issues with how they are written?  I'm no mod_rewrite expert.

Plus we have had a few users who reported IE bailing out on them when the WWW version of the URL was loaded but I can't see why?  Any advice?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} OTHERSITE.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://MAINSITE.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^sauces$ /sauces.php?sauce=our-hot-sauce [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sauces/([^/\.]+)/?$ /sauces.php?sauce=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^recipes/([^/\.]+)/?$ /recipes.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

# user has cleared recipe name but not cat AND left trailing slash
RewriteRule ^recipe/([^/\.]+)/$ /recipes.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

# has sauce/cat and recipe name
RewriteRule ^recipe/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /recipe.php?cat=$1&rec=$2 [L,QSA]

# user has cleared recipe name but not cat
RewriteRule ^recipe/([^/\.]+)$ /recipes.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1&sub=$2&subsub=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1&sub=$2&subsub=$3&subsubsub=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1&sub=$2&subsub=$3&subsubsub=$4&subsubsubsub=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Are the people coming to othersite via https as well? If so, then they're going to get ssl warnings about the hostname/certname mismatches, BEFORE any of your redirects can ever occur.

Comment: The only time someone would hit othersite.com using https would be if they had decided to type that in.  No references to that site under https exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest of the rules like fine but first 2 `301` rules can be combined into one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?OTHERSITE\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://MAINSITE.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```